# Air Conditioners Proccess

Tags: thermodynamics, humidity

When using cooling with dehumidification process sometimes the relative humidity increases, my question is that won't the blown air effect your skin by humidity due to this increase in relative humidity while our goal was to dehumidify for confort?

Comment: How does dehumidifying increase humidity? Do you mean refrigerated air or evaporative cooling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air conditioners owned by individuals will usually increase the relative humidity of the cool air that they generate, but the low temperature of that air results in more heat transfer from skin surfaces than the increase in relative humidity restricts cooling by perspiration.  Due to this, even though the cool air has a high relative humidity, it still cools the person who is in that air.

For commercial air conditioners, the evaporator is often located in one particular location while cool air is carried to a lot of different locations, some of which are far removed from the evaporator.  Due to this, the cool air heats up by several degrees before it gets distributed to the farthest parts of the A/C system.  To counter this, such systems will cool the air down substantially below thermostat settings, and such cooling will result in a lot of condensation of humidity from that air.  In order to meet various thermostat settings throughout a large system, small steam coils (or other heating devices) in various sectors of the system heat the extremely cold air up to the thermostat set point.  Such heating results in air that may well be lower in relative humidity than the "starting" air that was originally cooled by the evaporator.  For these systems, it's not a foregone conclusion that cooled air will have a higher relative humidity than the uncooled air that originally went through the evaporator.